# Error in fetch(key) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Tags: r

I have the following problem:

1. I have some development version of my package loaded in R session
2. I edited the source file.
3. I detach it and do:

   ```
   system("R CMD check realizedvolatility")
   system("R CMD build realizedvolatility")
   system("R CMD install realizedvolatility_0.1.tar.gz")
   library(realizedvolatility)
   ```
4. Until now, everything works. Now, if I try to bring up help file, for example `?realizedvolatility` , the error

   ```
   Error in fetch(key) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
   ```

occurs.

The remedy is to restart entirely the R session, then everything works. Is there any way to make it work within one session? I tried detaching from namespace, installing with various options, nothing worked.

I am using Mac OS X Lion, and R 2.14.1

Comment: I've got no personal experience with this, but I think package `devtools` is supposed to do these sorts of things, or at least help facilitate them: https://github.com/hadley/devtools

Comment: Interesting tools, but unfortunately, the problem still persists... :-/ Anyway thanks.

Comment: Same thing happens to me all the time. Just restart and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I asked the same question in R-help and one R core replied "this is by design" which means you cannot do anything about it except restarting R: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/283916.html (although I still do not understand why this design cannot refresh the cache database...)

Comment: Not a bug but a feature then... :) Thx a lot.